# Minimum Spanning Tree count given an edge that must be included

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

I am confused about the general form of a minimum spanning tree that includes an edge **e** that is not part of the minimum spanning tree. My question is:

Let **G** be a weighted graph with all the edges weight equal to 1. The MST of **G** does not include an edge **e**. How many MSTs can be made with the constraint that they include edge **e** ?

Comment: How can _include_ be at the same time _not part of_?

Comment: thats my question.is there any general form let say we have a tree with n vertices.there is one edge e when include this edge the MST has a cycle and it will not be MST any more. now what i have to do is to make an MST which has this edge e.is there any generic form through which i can find out how many MSTs are possible?

Comment: @Princess, would you please share a link about what you were saying?

Comment: I don't have any link. That statement is given me as a quiz. I did not find its answer. the answer which sir told is, "If there is an MST with n vertices then there would be n-1 MSTs that include the edge e". but as per my knowledge, its not possible. I saw in a presentation on internet that If we have a tree with 4 vertices then there possible MST would be 8.I am very much confused about this statement. I tried to find answer of this question on internet too but i could not get answer. after then i found the link of this site so i posted my question here.

Comment: So the question is actually whether _If there is an MST with n vertices then there would be n-1 MSTs that include the edge e_ is right?

Comment: The exact statement of the question is: "Let G be a weighted graph with all the edges weight equal to 1. Let T be a MST of G that does not include an edge e. Then how many MST can have e edge?"

Comment: What makes me confused is _Let T be a MST of G that does not include an edge e_ as this sentence seems unnecessary.

Comment: T is a minimum spanning tree which is a part of graph G and e is the edge that is not part of the MST but it is part of the graph

Comment: @Princess, without that sentence, the question is still valid.... I have got an answer for you.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you so much for your guidance

Comment: @Princess, so _check_ my answer XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a graph is unweighted, any spanning tree is a [Minimum Spanning Tree](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinimumSpanningTree.html).

*Identical weight of 1* can be considered the same as *unweighted*.

> In the mathematical field of graph theory [Kirchhoff's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem) or Kirchhoff's matrix tree theorem named after Gustav Kirchhoff is a theorem about the number of spanning trees in a graph.

Number (MST including e) = Number (All MST)<1> - Number (MST without e)<2>

<1> can be derived by Kirchhoff's theorem, and

<2> can be derived by Kirchhoff's theorem after removing e from the graph.

Comment: Thanks for the link the Kirchhoff's Theorem!  I haven't seen this before, but that is an *amazing* result!